# asp.net mvc hold action execution until event occurs

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In asp.net mvc I have registered an event listener in my action method. I want action method to wait until event occurs (therefore client will wait for server response until event occurs). Is there a nice way to do this without polling?

```
class SomeStateManager
{
    public delegate void SomeDelegate();
    public event SomeDelegate SomeEvent;
}

...

public void MyActionMethod(SomeData data)
{
    SomeStateManager man = GetSomeStateManager();
    man.SomeEvent += () =>
      {
          //want to hold action until this occurs, without polling
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an [AsyncController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.asynccontroller.aspx) can help. A [quick google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=mvc+async+controller) should yield plenty of info.

Note that it's not a good idea to wait for an event in a regular controller. While you wait the thread that is handling the request is blocked from doing anything else. Since there is a limited pool of threads available for requests you could end up blocking the entire application if enough concurrent requests are waiting on an event.